# Copy from columns only when not equal to false

Tags: excel-formula

I have 3 columns: Owner, General Manager and PR. For Owner the value could be False or Owner, For General Manager it could be False and General Manager and so on. The fourth column is called Relationship Key and should combine all of the values in each column excluding False e.g. False, General Manager and PR = General Manager, PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(A2,", ",B2,", ",C2),"FALSE, ",""),", FALSE",""),"FALSE","")
```